# Java code to replace a word in a file containing arithmetic operators

Tags: java, file, replace

I have written a code that replaces only a particular word in a file. The code works fine however if I want to replace a word containing an arithmetic operator in it the code doesn't work. I have also tried to escape special characters but still, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
public void replacePassword(String newPass, String oldPass, String destFile) throws IOException {

    Path filePath = Paths.get(destFile);
    String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));
    //System.out.println(fileContent);
    fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(oldPass), Matcher.quoteReplacement(newPass));
    //System.out.println(fileContent);
    Files.write(filePath, fileContent.getBytes());
}
```

Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Comment: You want to replace a literal string by another one. So don't use a regexp. Use the replace() method, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Arithmetic operators ( `+`, `*` ) have a special meaning in regular expressions (a pattern matching language), as which the first argument of `.replaceAll` is interpreted. Your attempts at escaping may have failed because you would need to _double escape_ (`"...\\+..."`), once for the literal string, once for the regular expression engine

Comment: @JBNizet I am unable to get you. I have used the replaceAll() method for replacing the  word. However it doesn;t work. Can you plz give me an example how to do it.

Comment: As I said, don't use replaceAll, use replace. Read the javadoc of both to understand the difference.

Comment: @collapsar I understood what you are saying but still not getting how to do it. Can you plz share an example with me.

Comment: Yes, but replace will do it for only one work. I have got multiple words in that file.

Comment: So, you haven't read the javadoc. Read the javadoc.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah I finally understood. I have read it just. It works. Thanx for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you want to use method replace(target, replacement) and not replaceAll(regex, replacement). The difference between this two methods is that the second one expect regex. If you have luck and do not give any special character for the regex then it will be considered as string and work properly. That why you did not have problems before.

So please just try to change the method with replace(target, replacement) and tell us if you still have a problem.

Example:

```
public void replacePassword(String newPass, String oldPass, String destFile) throws IOException
{

    Path filePath = Paths.get(destFile);
    String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));
    //System.out.println(fileContent);
    //Here you use replace method not replaceAll!
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(Matcher.quoteReplacement(oldPass), Matcher.quoteReplacement(newPass));
    //System.out.println(fileContent);
    Files.write(filePath, fileContent.getBytes());

}
```

Comment: Yes replace() function works. Thanks for the help :-)